# Aggregate Column from Data Frame 1 and Insert to Data Frame 2

Tags: r

I am using R 3.5.1.

I have the following data frames:  **Sales** and **Freight**.

```
> Freight = data.frame(CustomerId = c("A","A","B","B","C","C"), Product = c("1","2","1","2","1","2"), Cost=c(207,409,116,335,42,222))
> 
> Freight
  CustomerId Product Cost
1          A       1  207
2          A       2  409
3          B       1  116
4          B       2  335
5          C       1   42
6          C       2  222


> Sales_DF <- data.frame(CustomerID = c("A" ,"A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C"), TransactionDate = c("2/14/2018","1/7/2018","2/22/2018","1/14/2018","2/10/2018","1/13/2018","2/3/2018","1/14/2018", "2/19/2018","1/9/2018","2/20/2018","1/23/2018"),Shipment=c(176,54,175,60,118,262,257,470,474,438,82,305))
> Sales_DF
   CustomerID TransactionDate
1           A       2/14/2018
2           A        1/7/2018
3           A       2/22/2018
4           A       1/14/2018
5           B       2/10/2018
6           B       1/13/2018
7           B        2/3/2018
8           B       1/14/2018
9           C       2/19/2018
10          C        1/9/2018
11          C       2/20/2018
12          C       1/23/2018
   Shipment
1       176
2        54
3       175
4        60
5       118
6       262
7       257
8       470
9       474
10      438
11       82
12      305
```

How can I aggregate the shipments in **Sales** for each customer and for each month and insert it as a column to **Freight**?

Output wanted.

```
Customer    Month   Cost    Shipment
A             1      207    114
A             2      409    351
B             1      116    732
B             2      335    375
C             1       42    743
C             2      222    556
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a base R approach:

```
#convert the TransactionDate into month for joining with Freight
Sales_DF$Product <- as.POSIXlt(Sales_DF$TransactionDate, format="%m/%d/%Y")$mon + 1L

#merge Freight with aggregated Shipment
merge(Freight,
    #aggregate Shipment by CustomerID and Product
    aggregate(Shipment ~ CustomerID + Product, Sales_DF, sum), 
    by=c("CustomerID", "Product"))
```

data:

```
Freight <- data.frame(CustomerID = c("A","A","B","B","C","C"), Product = c("1","2","1","2","1","2"), Cost=c(207,409,116,335,42,222))
Sales_DF <- data.frame(CustomerID = c("A" ,"A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C"), TransactionDate = c("2/14/2018","1/7/2018","2/22/2018","1/14/2018","2/10/2018","1/13/2018","2/3/2018","1/14/2018", "2/19/2018","1/9/2018","2/20/2018","1/23/2018"),Shipment=c(176,54,175,60,118,262,257,470,474,438,82,305))
```

Comment: I get an error message: "Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column"

Comment: @Mr.T, you need to use the data that I posted. Otherwise you can type in the by.x and by.y manually

Comment: Ah, I see. The OP question used Id and ID. Missed that point. by.x would then be from Freight and by.y from Shipment? Maybe you can include this in your answer for R newbies like me?